# Python save txt file in a different folder

Tags: python, numpy

the following script is running well and saving the txt output in the Desktop as I am running the script from Desktop. However, I want to save the txt files to my Documents in a new folder named ASCII. How can I give the command for doing that. The 8phases.txt has the following lines-

```
-1  1   -1

-1  1   1

1   1   1

1   -1  1

-1  -1  -1

1   1   -1

1   -1  -1

-1  -1  1
```

The script-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D=12
n=np.arange(1,4)
x = np.linspace(-D/2,D/2, 3000)
I = np.array([125,300,75])
phase = np.genfromtxt('8phases.txt')

I_phase = I*phase

for count,i in enumerate(I_phase):
    F = sum(m*np.cos(2*np.pi*l*x/D) for m,l in zip(i,n))
    s = np.column_stack([x,F])
    np.savetxt((str(count)+'.txt'),s)
```

Any help please-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably provide full path in argument of savetxt method, for example:

```
np.savetxt(r"C:\ASCII\%s.txt" % count,s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
from os.path import osp
userdoc = osp.join(osp.expanduser("~"),'Documents')
np.savetxt(osp.join(userdoc, "%s.txt" % count),s)
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. The first answer is working though. But its good to know other way around

Comment: The only difference is that in this case you are getting the user's home directory dynamically instead of hardcoding that.

Comment: @OHLÁLÁ Thanks a lot for this answer - I think it should be `import os.path as osp` instead of `from os.path import osp` - at least the latter did not work for me