# Numpy savetxt: How to save file into a relative path?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, export-to-csv

I'm fairly new to Python, and haven't found the answer to this straightforward question.

How can I export an array to a CSV file using a relative path within my working directory?

I managed to successfully *read* data using numpy and a relative path:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('resources/myfile.csv', dtype=float, skip_header=1, delimiter=',')
```

But trying to *export* to a relative path using numpy.savetxt apparently requires to use an absolute path (cf. answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519290/python-save-txt-file-in-a-different-folder)). 
My attempt to use a relative path gives the following error:

```
np.savetxt('bin/myresults.csv', data, delimiter=",")
```

Error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'bin/myresults.csv'

Is there an easy way to create such a file without entering the full path? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: It should work, but it won't create subdirectories for you. The error looks like you don't have `bin` in your home directory.

Comment: does `./bin/myresults.csv` work?

Comment: Thanks Gosha... My bad, I had recently moved the .py script in a subfolder, and didn't think to grab bin along. Thanks for putting me on the right tracks!  What finally works now is '../bin/data_wsm.csv'